# nodejs cant connect to mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

so all my applications were working just fine using mongoose, all of a sudden they all stopped. i cant connect to my database. however my deployed apps using mongoose databases work fine, but i cant access to any database using my local computer. here is a test server ive written. can someone help me whats happening.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

app.use(express.json())

const db = require('./keys').mongoURI;

mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server running'))



module.exports = {
    mongoURI: 'mongodb+srv://ertemishakk:<password>@cluster0-xi4zx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
}
```

Terminal:
server running
MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/ishakertem/Desktop/test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server_selection.js:308:9)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:536:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:480:7) {
  name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
}

Comment: Whether mongo is running on the specified Instance??\

Comment: i killed all nodes, so nothing running

Comment: You are saying mongo is not running?? Then how it will connect??

Comment: mongo is running, installed

Comment: whether you are able to ping that mongo instance?? Also check mongo.conf for `bindIP` property.

Comment: ip configs are set and open to all ips, i can connect to db using mongo driver but not mongoose

Comment: can you access your mongo shell from terminal? I think the remote server is not responding to your connection request

Comment: no that doesnt work as well, i dont know whats missing, ive spent my whole day on it

Comment: are you able to connect to local database? check if server is restricting your request.

Comment: can you explain how?

Comment: just tried using mongoDB Compass, I get Server selection timed out after 30000 ms, not connecting to database...

Comment: ok. just accessed another wifi and its working, it must me firewall or something. Does anyone have any idea about how to configure the settings

Answer (score 0):

You should check your

> bindIp : [public_ip]

option in

> mongod.conf

file.
It should be pointed out to public IP of that system on which MongoDB is running.
You can use 0.0.0.0 for debuging only, because it is exposed One.

[DO VOTE TO THIS ANSWER, IF ITS HELPFUL TO YOU]

Comment: I dont have mongb on my local server, accessing cloud using node

Comment: Have you tried with putting publicIP in bindIp option? [You also need to restart the mongodb after update in config]

Comment: I don't know how to access publicIP in bindIP option. as far as I know, they only exist in local mongodb which I don't use.I use cloud base

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Follow This Code I hope solved your problem**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

app.use(express.json())


//Remove <password> and provide DB password
/**
 * Example: mongodb + srv: //ertemishakk:123@cluster0-xi4zx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majorit
 */
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://ertemishakk:<password>@cluster0-xi4zx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majorit', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log('connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server running'))
```